# Masyu puzzle with secret code

Tags: cipher, grid-deduction, masyu

[image]

What secret code is hidden in this masyu puzzle?

Note: The regions marked with x are not to be drawn

Comment: Please forgive me if I'm wrong, but I'm not convinced this 'masyu' puzzle has a unique logically deducible solution... I'm failing to see much beyond [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdHsI.png). My suspicion is that this is instead intended to conceal rot13(n zrffntr va Oenvyyr) but I'm not seeing a way to apply it consistently across the whole puzzle.

Comment: You can try to link the others together, it will reveal a (Sbhe ahzore) code

Comment: I found a legal solution where the hidden code is rot(guerr, svir, qbt, pnpghf)

Comment: There are *many* ways to "link the others together" - I don't think that this will necessarily be findable.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, even the updated one is still not uniqely solvable.. (I can't go further than this one: https://imgur.com/a/O4fazI9).

Comment: I have updated the puzzle again, hope this works!

Comment: @00xxqhxx00 As a puzzle creator (especially for grid deduction puzzles), you're not supposed to "hope this works". It's your responsibility to check that it is uniquely solvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X's scattered all over the board makes it a rather dull and mechanical puzzle, and still there is an ambiguity at the lower left corner:

> [image]

How to get to this point:

> Observe that the X's make the entire cell unusable, and therefore they act like the outer boundary for white/black pearls nearby. Specifically, if a white pearl is adjacent to an X, it means the line should pass straight through it in a specific way (e.g. horizontally if X is right above or below it). If a black pearl is adjacent to/one cell away from X, the line should extend from it two units in the opposite direction. Once this step is complete, proceed with usual single-loop deductions: avoid making a closed loop too early or making a dead end.

Assuming the edge goes straight vertically so it looks like this:

> [image]

then the secret code is

> **3564**, reading the digits horizontally. Note that the digit shapes overlap a little bit.